# Iterate v.export on GRASS 7.8.5 through Python 3 using a list and SQL

Tags: python, grass-gis, sql

I would like to iterate an analysis on a vector for each unique value present on his attribute table. The first step is to extract different vector according to the unique identifier, but the SQL formula doesn't work. It should be `Site_ID='site'`, instead is  `Site_ID=site`. I am using GRASS 7.8.5 and python 3, launched from the GRASS shell.

Desired behavior: extract groups of features from a vector by a unique identifier using a list

Error: The formula is not able to insert the correct SQL expression. It should be `Site_ID='site'`, instead is  `Site_ID=site`.

```
import os
import grass.script as script

area_allsites = 'input vector'

# Create a list with site names from the column Site_ID
sitelist1 = gscript.read_command('v.db.select',
    map=area_allsites,
    columns='Site_ID',
    flags='c',
    overwrite = overwrite)

sitelist2 = sitelist1.split(os.linesep) 
sitelist=list(set(sitelist2)) # remove duplicates

# Reiterate trough area_allsites using the list names
for site in sitelist:
    formula = 'Site_ID =' + site
    gscript.run_command('v.extract',
        input=area_allsites,
        where=formula,
        output=('area' + site),
        overwrite = overwrite)
```

Comment: The line `formula = 'Site_ID =' site`  delivers `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, maybe a starting point to fix the code. It doesn't even reach the `v.extract` line (I run your script locally)...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @markusN. Unfortunately, I knew that the problem is there, but I really don't know how to fix the formula. Do you have any suggestion on how to correctly recall the object site in the formula or in `v.extract` itself? Thank you.